# NodeJS - Is host reacheable without ICMP

Tags: node.js

I've the need to check if an host is reacheable or not. This machine have ICMP protocol disabled, so i can't send a simple "ping" on it.

The machine is up, network is ok but i cant ping it.

There is a way to "understand" if an host is reacheable without using ICMP ? (like nmap).

Another point, i will have to do this on Windows and Linux, my NodeJS application should work on "any" OS.

Thanks

Comment: There are many ways, such as doing a tcp-based ping (ok not an ICMP ping but still a valid approach). You can search for this type of thing and will find lots of info about it.

Comment: I've tried out tcp-ping library (for nodejs) but i do not get response from the host.... I should "send a packed" on the IP layer to skip all the services. What i just need is a sort of "is reacheable", i dont care on what services are up, i just want to know if the machine is up.... So, i havent to specify any port..

Comment: I guess if host just drops every incoming packet you have no way to tell if it's reachable or not